# Loading a unique page depending on id for a social network

Tags: php

I am creating a social network. I have created a profile page and a newsfeed-type page which navigates you to the profile page.

I am trying to easily create a unique basic profile layout depending on the data you have entered on another script. I have a session variable ($_SESSION['id']), which I am trying to grab, move the user to the page based on that, and load the results that match the id in the MySQL table. However, data dependent on the id doesn't seem to be working. Below are extracts from key scripts:

*Navigation menu to Profile*

```
<?

         function fetch_new_users()
        {
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `username` FROM `users` WHERE username='{$_SESSION['user_login']}'");
            $mysql = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

            return $mysql;
        }

        $users = fetch_new_users();
        ?>
        <?
        if (isset($_SESSION["user_login"])) {

        echo '

        <div class="fnav">


                 <?php foreach($users as $user): ?>
                            <p>
                                <a href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $user[\'id\']; ?>" >Profile</a>
                            </p>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>

        </div><!-- end fnav -->
```

*Creation of the session variable when you log in*

```
if(isset($_POST["user_login"]) && isset($_POST["password_login"]))
{
    $user_login = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["user_login"]); // filter everything but numbers and letters
    $password_login = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["password_login"]); // filter everything but numbers and letters
    $md5password_login = md5($password_login);
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$user_login' AND password='$md5password_login' LIMIT 1"); // query the person
    //Check for their existance
    $userCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); //Count the number of rows returned
    if($userCount == 1)
    {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
        {
            $id = $row["id"];
        }
        $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
        $_SESSION["user_login"] = $user_login;
        $_SESSION["password_login"] = $password_login;
        exit("<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0\">");
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'That information is incorrect, try again';
        exit();
    }
```

*The actual grabbing of the data from the MySQL table*

```
    $id1 = $_GET['id'];
//check user exists
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id='$id1'");
$get = mysql_fetch_assoc($check);
$username = $get['username'];
$firstname = $get['first_name'];
```

Comment: `session_start()` is at the top of each script, correct?  Also, look at what syntax highlighting is telling you with your first script's `echo`....

Comment: not at the top of each script, the top script i have and just include

Comment: Well, like I tried hinting about above, with the code you have written, you have a syntax error with the first `echo` in your first snippet.  You're already within PHP at that point, but then try entering PHP *again* in order to output the proper link.  That's a no go, and really highlights a flaw in your design - jumping between HTML and PHP.  Well formed PHP scripts do **ALL** data processing up front, and then echo the results in templates.  Not doing that results in the kind of mess you have, where debugging means digging through the syntax of two languages.

Comment: how can i fix the code to work?

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental problem here is using/abusing PHP's ability to jump between itself and HTML on a whim.  While it's widely touted as a feature, for anything non-trivial it usually winds up resulting in a horrible spaghetti dish of server side code, markup, and client side scripting, all embedded and woven around each other.  The solution is **not to write code that way.**

Now, that's easy to say, but what does that *mean*?  It means treating PHP like the standalone language it really is.  It also means embracing the HTTP request cycle and doing all data handling/process up front.

So, when you get a request - either GET or POST - instead of jumping right away to write some HTML to show the user something, stop.  Don't write any markup at all.  Instead, handle the request first.

In your case, you want to display a link to the user's profile page.  That means:

1. determining who the user is
2. generating the correct link based on that info

You already have the guts of it correct with your function (edited to make it easier to read (double quoted strings are your friend)), so start with that:

```
function fetch_new_users()
{
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `username` FROM `users` WHERE username={$_SESSION['user_login']");
    $mysql = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $newresult = $mysql;

    return $newresult;
}

$users = fetch_new_users();
```

Now, instead of echoing it all right then and there, continue to do any processing you may need.  You already have the results of your function in the `$users` variable, so there's no need to spit it out immediately.  Just process your data and store the results in a variable.

When you're ready to actually display the info, create the entire template:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <!-- stuff -->

    <body>
        <!-- more stuff -->

        <?php foreach($users as $user): ?>
            <p>
                <a href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $user['id']; ?>" >Profile</a>
            </p>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Your templates (which can be `include()`-ed) should only have the bare minimum of PHP in them.  `echo`, `if/else`, `while()`, `for()`, and `foreach()` should be the limit of what they contain.  It's not the job of the template to handle form data, query a database, or any other such fun stuff.

Splitting scripts up like this is an example of **Separation of Concerns**, which basically says that apps should be split into components based on what they do.  So, much like how CSS should be separate from HTML (one is formatting while the other is structure), so too should PHP be separate from HTML, with the exception of displaying things.

TLDR: structure your apps better and don't follow any resources that recommend jumping between PHP and HTML.  You'll only end up learning the wrong way to write PHP apps.

Comment: There's a nifty side benefit from the "process first, *then* display results" way of structuring apps.  You know those "Headers already sent" errors?  They essentially disappear.

Comment: Also, as a PSA, **don't** use the old `mysql_*` functions.  They're soft deprecated.  Instead, use either MySQLi or PDO.  In your case, probably MySQLi as they have a procedural/'normal'/non-OOP API.  The old functions are kinda sucky, and lead to security issues.

Comment: still the same thing mate. nothing seems to have changed. any ideas how to not improve the look of the code but what it actually does

Comment: Can you update your question to show your current code?  And maybe clarify your app flow?  The third snippet you listed is a bit confusing in terms of where it fits in.  But, regardless, my answer still stands as general advice.  Dismissing it as just being about code style is shortsighted at best.