# Checking if radiobutton is checked using POST

Tags: php, html, forms, radio-button

I'm trying to redirect the user to another webpage depending on which radio button they have checked.

Here is the relevant code:

```
  <form action="sample.php" method="post">
          <input name="survey" type="radio" value="Yes" /> Yes
          </br>
          <input name="survey" type="radio" value="No"  /> No
  </form>

  <? 
    if ($_POST['survey'] == "Yes")
    {
        header('Location: http://localhost/survey.php');
    }
    else if ($_POST['survey'] == "No")
    {
        header('Location: http://localhost/survey.php');
    }

  ?>
```

For some reason or another I get an error within my if statement. That does not recognize 'survey' as a valid index. How Am I failing to do something to link my form to the php code?

Comment: is it one document or 2 seperate files?

Comment: This code is in a single file. But the redirect is to another file.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? I am using radio buttons?

Answer (score 2):

Your warning is caused by the fact that when you load the page using `GET` (a normal request), `$_POST['survey']` is not set.

You could change your conditions by adding a `isset($_POST['survey'] ) &&` in front of every time you use it or you could put the whole code in a block that checks if a post was made like:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
{
    if ($_POST['survey'] == "Yes")
    {
        header('Location: http://localhost/survey.php');
    }
    else if ($_POST['survey'] == "No")
    {
        header('Location: http://localhost/survey.php');
    }
}
else
{
  // output html
}
```

Either way you would have to put this in front of your html as you cannot use `header` if the headers have already been sent (stuff has already been outputted to the browser).

Comment: Thanks. You explained the concepts really well. I'm new to programming, and that was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Think about how forms work:

The first time you visit your page, the form is **not** submitted.  Yet, your `if/else` is acting as though it were.  That's what's causing the error - `$_POST['survey']` doesn't exist the first time.

Write your scripts properly - do *all* potential form processing before rendering HTML:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // handle the form
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Blah</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- code -->
    </body>
</html>
```

That will allow you to check if you've submitted the form to itself, and potentially use a `header()` to redirect the user without running into those pesky "Headers already sent" errors.

Comment: A bit more about how to structure your code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13371294/399584  Long story short, jumping back and forth between PHP and HTML only leads to tears.  Don't do it.  Instead, do all your PHP work up front, then display results.

Answer (score 0):

Try a simple print_r() statement to see if $_POST has any contents at all. Put this at the top of the page:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Also, be sure that you're loading the results page via the form. If you just type the URL of the page it will not have any POST data sent with it.

Answer (score 0):

The first time you load your file sample.php there is no POST data, therefore there's no index 'survey'.

You need to nest it in another if statement or modify it the following:

```
  <form action="sample.php" method="post">
          <input name="survey" type="radio" value="Yes" /> Yes
          </br>
          <input name="survey" type="radio" value="No"  /> No
  </form>

  <? 
    if (isset($_POST) && $_POST['survey'] == "Yes")
    {
        header('Location: http://localhost/survey.php');
    }
    else if (isset($_POST) && $_POST['survey'] == "No")
    {
        header('Location: http://localhost/survey.php');
    }

  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using a different php file for the checking.

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="another.php" method="POST">
  <label>You are: </label> Male <input type="radio" name="male">  Female     <input type="radio" name="female"><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="GO">
</body>
</html>
```

*****another.php******

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    if(empty($_POST['male']) && empty($_POST['female'])) 
    {echo "select gender";}
    elseif (empty($_POST['female'])) //means Male is checked
     {
        $gend="Male";
          echo $gend;
    }
    elseif(empty($_POST['male'])) //Means Female is checked
    { 
       $gend="Female";
          echo $gend; 
    }
    elseif(empty($_POST['male']) || empty($_POST['female'])== false) //Not required if you can disable one when another is checked
        {echo"please select only one";}
}
?>
```